# Ajax test (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, I have been struggling with making ajax work.
Here is my previous question: [AJAX (admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?action=) Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411277/ajax-admin-urladmin-ajax-phpaction-not-found/31411895?noredirect=1#comment50805114_31411895)

Anyway, I decided to narrow down and only have necessary files.

Here is the set up.

**test.php**

```
  <div class="test">
       <a href="#test_demo" id="demo">Items</a>      
  </div>
  <div id="test_demo"> </div>  


<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.test a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tab_id = jQuery('this').attr('id'); 


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'test_tab', id: tab_id}),
            success: function(data){
                  jQuery('#test_' + tab_id).html(data);

        },
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
        }  

        }); 

     }); 
     }); 


</script>
```

**function.php**

```
function test_tab_callback() {       
    $template_part_path = 'page-parts/test_' . $_GET['id'];
    get_template_part($template_part_path);
    exit;
 }
add_action('wp_ajax_test_tab', 'test_tab_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_tab', 'test_tab_callback');
```

**test_demo.php**

```
<div id="test_demo_content">Demo Content</div>
```

Here is the my idea on how it should work.

1. test.php: When user clicks `Items` button, then the `tab_id`variable in the jQuery saves the anchor `id` (in this case, it will be `id="demo"`).
2. Then admin-ajax.php is called.
3. The saved id ("demo") is then passed onto the function.php and it is used in the variable `$template_part_path = 'page-parts/test_' . $_GET['id'];` which gives `page-parts/test_demo` for `test_demo.php`
4. Then the template part is called and calledback to the jQuery.
5. Then the data is "insert" into the `jQuery('#test_' + tab_id).html(data);` which is `id="test_demo`.
6. The test_demo.php content should be displayed in the `#test_demo` div.

But it is not working. I used `console.log(data)` but showed no result. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A href attribute on `div` element is invalid (in test.php, div with id test_demo

Comment: Opps, it is fixed. (not the actual problem). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I got the javascript working in my answer but can't test the php side of things. Can you please apply the fix and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: I got it working by removing the quotation mark as you pointed it out! =) You just made my day! haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your getting the jquery object of "this" you can't use the quotes. This was making tab_id as undefined and ruining the rest.

Here is what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/7r1dg7L4/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.test a').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 
         alert(tab_id);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! =))) I got it working! I can't believe that simple quotation ruined last 2 days of my life.! Thank you so much for pointing out the problem!

Comment: no problem. Welcome to programming / development. I have stared at code for hours and missed one upper case letter that ruined everything :)

Comment: Haha. It surely forces you to be a perfectionist in order for things to work. lol. Thank you Bill! =)

Comment: Kiiiim!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394844/ajax-tabs-wordpress#comment50770248_31394844